# ListView with three options on same activity

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost, segmentedcontrol

I have a list View and now I am trying to set up  tab view for this list view.

Now sometime there are 3 options, sometimes 2 and sometimes 1. As you can see here

[image]

And when a tab is clicked I will reload my list view with new data depending on which item in the tab bar was clicked. But this is similar data, so it will be in the same list view and I want to use the same xml layout. But currently I am unable to do this, I can't see to get it working it.

Here is what I have so

```
 myTabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);
    myTabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    spec1.setIndicator("First Tab", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add));
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    myTabHost.addTab(spec1);

    myTabHost.addTab(myTabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab").
            setIndicator("Second Tab", getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit)).setContent(R.id.tab2));
```

This is setting it up for 2 tab, and then in the xml I have

```
<include
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/item_list_view">


            </include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/test">


            </include>
```

But I want to use the same layout instead of different ones and just reload the data but when I set the tabs .setContent to the same id it doesn't work?

So the basic question is how do I use the same xml for more than one tab, and just load different data in the list view?

The tab bar will be filled with text not images if that matters. Have looked at some tutorals on this but aren't helpful for my situation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeNC_sShJXs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-u3toC6ctY

So I need some help setting this up.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Try to ask question as simple.You can use expected output with images , & lot of options are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, this question involves two parts:

1. Creating tabs programmatically.
2. Sharing the same content view between tabs.

For the first part, you can put an "empty" [`TabHost`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) in your layout, and then call [`addTab()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#addTab%28android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec%29) later, depending on the tabs you want to show. For example, the layout file would be just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TabHost01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And then, in `onCreate()`:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);
tabHost.setup();
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(...));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(...));
```

Where each [`TabHost.TabSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html) specifies the indicator and content of each tab.

Now, as to the second part, you need a **single** `ListView` widget and change its data as the user switches tabs. This is actually pretty easy, since the `TabHost` can handle the case where multiple tabs have the same content without problems. You just need to set up a [`TabHost.TabContentFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabContentFactory.html) for each tab, and have each of them return the *same* view.

For example:

```
mListView = new ListView(this);

TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);
tabHost.setup();
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("First").setContent(mDummyTabContent));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("2").setIndicator("Second").setContent(mDummyTabContent));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("3").setIndicator("Third").setContent(mDummyTabContent));
```

where `mTabContent` is initialized as:

```
private final TabHost.TabContentFactory mDummyTabContent = new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
{
    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag)
    {
        return mListView;
    }
};
```

Then the last remaining step is to add a [`TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html) that switches the data in the single `ListView`:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(mOnTabChangedListener);
mOnTabChangedListener.onTabChanged("1");
```

where:

```
private TabHost.OnTabChangeListener mOnTabChangedListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
        String[] data;

        if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            data = FIRST_ITEMS;
        else if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            data = SECOND_ITEMS;
        else
            data = THIRD_ITEMS;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FakeTabViewActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
};
```

Sample gist with activity and layout file is available [here](https://gist.github.com/matiash/2910ae26fe8eb4cf5ed6).

Comment: okay looks good just about to implement it where is the list view found by its ID, or where is it located? from the xml file that has the list view?

Comment: See gist for full list view and adapter, https://gist.github.com/spennyf/3241dd694af464c7e576

Comment: @iqueqiorio In the example I posted it's created programmatically in `onCreate()`, but you might as well use `LayoutInflater.inflate()` instead

Comment: okay I see where you made it, but how should I change it for my custom list view and custom adapter?, also my data is being loaded from the web, so I don't want to display until I have loaded my data

Comment: @iqueqiorio I saw your XML. Since it contains only the `HeaderListView` (plus a LinearLayout that is not necessary) you might as well create it programmatically (it's even simpler). For the second part, use an `AsyncTask` in `onTabChanged()` to load the data and set the adapter as it arrives.

Comment: Okay I think I have got do you know how to change the indicator color programatically? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609989/set-color-tab-host-indicator

Comment: @iqueqiorio I'll answer in the other question, but please give me a couple of hours. At work now :)

Comment: yes whenever you get a chance I add a bounty on it too when the 2 days have past, thanks you have been very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Add TabHost view to your layout. You can add as many tabs you want dynamically using addTab() method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TabHost myTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
myTabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);
            mytabhost.setup();

TabSpec spec = mytabhost.newTabSpec("tab_creation");
spec.setIndicator("Create adresse",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add));
    spec.setContent(R.id.onglet1);
    mytabhost.addTab(spec);

    mytabhost.addTab(mytabhost.newTabSpec("tab_inser").setIndicator("Delete",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit)).setContent(R.id.Onglet2));

   mytabhost.addTab(mytabhost.newTabSpec("tab_affiche").setIndicator("Show All",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view)).setContent(R.id.Onglet3));

   ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
   MyListAdapter adapter =new MyListAdapter(this);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);              
 }
}
```

for complete reference:http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-activity-android-with-a-tabhost-view/27990

Comment: okay but my xml is going to to be the same for each tab, what would I change?

Comment: you can use setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener l) mehtod and reset the adapter there with new values.

Comment: okay, so I have it setup and mostly working but when I have the current tab set to 0 the data is not loaded? but if it is set to 1 it does load

Comment: Initially load data for 0th tab by default and set it. Then on change of tab load data for other tabs.

Comment: When I set onglet1 and Onglet2 to the same layout it doesn't load? How can I use the same xml for more than one tab