# Set color tab host indicator

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How do you set the color of the tab host indicator color I want to change the light blue default color to lets says RED.

[image]

And I need to this programatically as I am making the tabs programatically.

I did some research and looked at this example but it does not work for me. With the progamtic approach.

[TabWidget current tab bottom line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color)

Thanks

Comment: Actually, the solution in the linked answer works, even if the tabs are added programmatically. Did you try it? Are you encountering any problems?

Comment: @matiash yes but I don't want the color to always be white

Comment: Just to clarify... do you need to change the color dynamically? As in, one time they're red and the next they're blue? That's also possible, but slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programmatically, even change the color as you want, by following the solution in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color) you mention, plus adding a [`ColorFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) to adjust the color.

So:

1. Create the appropriate drawable. The easiest way, as mentioned in one of the answers, is using https://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
2. Place into your project the `tab_indicator_ab_example.xml` (in drawable) plus the 6 associated png files (tab_*.png) for each drawable density.
3. After creating the tabs, use the code that iterates over the `TabWidget` child views to set their background, **however:**
4. Instead of setting the drawable as-is, *use a color filter to change its color to the desired one*.

Instead of this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
    ... /* same as before */

    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_tab_selector_drawable);
}
```

write something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
    ... /* same as before */

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab_example);
    d.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
```

Comment: yes one time when it is open I want it lets say GREEN and another time RED. I add the xml file to my drawable correct?

Comment: @iqueqiorio From the zip that the style generator creates, copy those I mentioned into your project's res.

Comment: Okay got it :) the only thing is it says that `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated is there a way around this, I just don't like using deprecated methods

Comment: @iqueqiorio you can use setbackground in jelly bean or later and the old method for previous versions.